# Can't connect to Wireless Network

Tags: wireless

I am using *WiFi Radar* to connect to Wireless Networks, but it never connects me. I can see all the available networks, when I pick one and try to connect, the connection screen never goes away and it never connects.

Comment: Have you checked the routers you are trying to connect with? Do you have any other devices that you can confirm will connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using `wifi-radar` instead of the Ubuntu default
[network-manager-gnome](http://packages.ubuntu.com/network-manager-gnome) [image: Install network-manager-gnome] package?

Wifi-radar was last built for [Karmic Koala](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wifi-radar/2.0.s05-1) and may have drifted out of "works well with others" territory. I'm guessing that wifi-radar isn't playing nice with the DHCP or WPA mechanisms.

Comment: Hi msw, I actually saw Wi fi radar is some forum, where people suggested that to use for Netwrok connectivity. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @ msw, Not sure if it was the default network-manager-gnome, but I used the Network icon in system tray and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: It's truly a shame no one has been able to figure out using Wifi-radar as prioritizing networks is unavailable in network-manager-gnome.